How to Identify Numbers from WAV Files for Comparison?
I have an HTTP request that returns an audio file where Google's voice speaks a sequence of 6 numbers in Portuguese, ranging from 0 to 9, separated by silence. I have saved WAV files in my development environment with the audio of each of the possible numbers. Now, I want to extract a segment of raw data from each of these WAV files to compare it with the audio chunk received from the HTTP request.
For example, in the following Python code, different binary segments are used for comparison, but I need to know how to select representative segments from my WAV files. How can I achieve this?
def discaptcher(file_content):
    # legacy code, other audio
    footprints_to_numbers = {
        b"\x72\x00\x77\x00\x7a\x00\x4a\x00\x58\x00\x7a\x00\x55\x00\x53\x00": "0",  # noqa
        b"\x86\x00\x7f\x00\x8c\x00\x7f\x00\x71\x00\x62\x00\x52\x00\x52\x00": "1",  # noqa
        b"\x15\x00\x1e\x00\x1b\x00\x05\x00\x16\x00\x1b\x00\x20\x00\x17\x00": "2",  # noqa
        b"\x8e\xff\x85\xff\x8c\xff\x85\xff\x79\xff\xb6\xff\xbd\xff\xaa\xff": "3",  # noqa
        b"\xfd\xff\x0b\x00\x0f\x00\xf6\xff\xd7\xff\xcf\xff\xbb\xff\xb2\xff": "4",  # noqa
        b"\x87\x00\x85\x00\x7c\x00\x77\x00\x7b\x00\x81\x00\x79\x00\x7f\x00": "5",  # noqa
        b"\x65\xff\x87\xff\xb1\xff\xa3\xff\x6a\xff\x20\xff\x26\xff\x2c\xff": "6",  # noqa
        b"\xb9\xfe\xbb\xfe\xae\xfe\xa6\xfe\xa1\xfe\xb8\xfe\xd2\xfe\xfb\xfe": "7",  # noqa
        b"\x5b\xff\x66\xff\x90\xff\x85\xff\x76\xff\x75\xff\x79\xff\x75\xff": "8",  # noqa
        b"\x16\x01\x1e\x01\x29\x01\x13\x01\x0b\x01\x05\x01\x06\x01\xf8\x00": "9",
    }  # noqa

    captcha_dict = {}

    captcha = ""

    for snd, lt in footprints_to_numbers.items():
        pos = [m.start() for m in regex.finditer(regex.escape(snd), file_content)]

        for i in pos:
            captcha_dict[i] = lt

    for key in sorted(captcha_dict.keys()):
        captcha += captcha_dict[key]

    return captcha

I tried, after the initial HTTP request, to split the received audio into chunks using the split_on_silence method from pydub and then chunk.export('filename.wav', format='wav'), but the comparison between two files representing the same number doesn't work. I also attempted to generate MD5 hashes for the WAV files, but in this case, the comparison also failed.

I would compare the files after silence split in a DAW manually to get an idea as to what is wrong. Could be the bit depth is different or the sampling rate. The length could be slightly different, you split the incoming data on silence but the comparison files may still contain silence as padding. Finally, you have to be certain the output from google is identical each time. It seems unlikely a modern speech synthesis engine would produce identical output, at which point you are looking at a speech-to-text engine.

you should forward the waves you receive from google to a speech-to-text service
